# Export specific customer data incl. orders to another instance

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise

I'm working for a customer that has several Magento Instances (from local, to stage, to test, to production). On production, customers are creating unreproducable behaviours which developers would like to verify and fix.

However, its been a complicated task to export specific customer data in an granular way.

Is there any smart way to export Magento Customer Data incl. Order details + Addresses to another Magento Database?

I was thinking about doing regular collection calls to Magento and "fake" SQL insert commands in order to provide developers ways to import Customers and Orders into their local Database without copying the full and live DB at all. I've now created a shell script that loads the customer based on its email, but from there on I guess I have a hard time since I do not fully see if I got every single customer data aspect in here.

How could I do that in a good way?